# design pattern for nondeterministic operation (nondet. factory?)

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Suppose I have this recurring block of code:

```
Class1 c1;
try {
    c1.parse(x);
} catch(Exception& e) {
    Class2 c2;
    try {
        c2.parse(x);
    } catch(Exception& e) {
        Class3 c3;
        try {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Obviously, what I am interested in, is the first `Class#` (#=1,2,3,...) instance for which parse does not throw an exception.

Optionally, `Class1`, ..., `ClassN` have a common superclass, and I can use that as a return type.

What is a **concise** way to abstract this operation, considering it will recurr many times in the code?

Ok to use STL and Boost, not ok to use C++11, because of project requirements :(
Macros are a gray zone.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking about. May be you can give a more concise example? Are you just trying to find an actual serialized type by trying to deserialize the message into any of the types you have in the programm? That's an extremely bad design. If it is something else, please clarify.

Comment: You are abusing exception handling for normal control flow. If you instead give state to `ClassX` and make them convertible to `bool` to check for success you can solve this easily.

Comment: @SergeyA, I thing you guessed right. The input is an XML DOM, and I want to parse it to fit my class hierarchy, or throw an exception. This particular aspect is when the parsing can be ambiguous, and must try to parse an XML element with many possible classes.

Comment: Why can't you indicate the actual type as an element in XML? If it is not possible, than follow @nwp advice - but I believe knowing the type from the message is better than guessing.

Comment: @nwp: exceptions are useful in my use case. Imagine that the parse method is called recursively (e.g. because `Dog::parse()` will try to call `Leg::parse()`), exceptions are catch and rethrown so to build an error string containing the complete stack (i.e. tree path), which otherwise I would have to track manually, for example by passing a stack container on the [call] stack.

Comment: You may look at how to iterate over types. (for example: `template <typename ... Ts> TryParse(X& x);`)

Comment: @Jarod42 OP specified that 11 is not possible. Yet, this question reeks of bad design tbh.

Comment: @Jarod42 He wrote he can't use c++11. He could use boost::mpl::list instead.

Comment: @nwp If he already wrote a lot of methods which throw or if he uses methods api which has methods which throw he would have to write this `try { } catch (...) { return false; } return true;` construction in every method

Comment: Normally I am a strong advocate for the use of exceptions, but it seems to me that in this case, failure to parse is an *expected outcome* - i.e. not exceptional. Might it not be cleaner to return a status code/object indicating parsing success or failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without variadics, and limited to c++03 we're forced to do it the way the boost libraries do it - lots of boilerplate up front in return for convenient expression later on:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Class1 { void parse(const std::string&); };
struct Class2 { void parse(const std::string&); };
struct Class3 { void parse(const std::string&); };

struct none_type {};

template<class C>
  struct try_impl
  {
    try_impl(int index)
      : _index(index)
      {
      }
    void apply(int& which, C& c, const std::string& s) const
    {
      if (which >= 0)
        return;
      try {
        c.parse(s);
        which = _index;
      }
      catch(...) {
        // logging here?
      }
    }

    int _index;
  };

template<>
  struct try_impl<none_type>
  {
    try_impl(int index)
      : _index(index)
      {
      }
    void apply(int& which, none_type& c, const std::string& s) const
    {
    }

    int _index;
  };

// attempt to parse all given objects. Return the index of the first one that 
// passed
// return -1 if non parse correctly
//
template<class C1, class C2 = none_type, class C3 = none_type, class C4 = none_type, class C5 = none_type>
struct parse_attempt_impl
{
  static int apply(const std::string& s,C1 c1, C2 c2 = C2(), C3 c3 = C3(), C4 c4 = C4(), C5 c5 = C5())
{
  int which = -1;
  try_impl<C1>(0).apply(which, c1, s);
  try_impl<C2>(1).apply(which, c2, s);
  try_impl<C3>(2).apply(which, c3, s);
  try_impl<C4>(3).apply(which, c4, s);
  try_impl<C5>(4).apply(which, c5, s);
  return which;
}
};

// you will need to make as many of these as you need
template<class C1, class C2, class C3>
int parse_attempt(const std::string& s, C1 c1, C2 c2, C3 c3)
{
  return parse_attempt_impl<C1, C2, C3>::apply(s, c1, c2, c3);
}

template<class C1, class C2, class C3, class C4>
int parse_attempt(const std::string& s, C1 c1, C2 c2, C3 c3, C4 c4)
{
  return parse_attempt_impl<C1, C2, C3, C4>::apply(s, c1, c2, c3, c4);
}



int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  std::string x(argv[1]);
  int which = parse_attempt(x, Class1(), Class2(), Class3());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, please. It hurts. Use 'named constructors' that return a std::optional (i.e., in class T: static std::optional Create(...)) and make your internal constructor private / protected. Ok, if you really have to (or use a library you cannot change) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct ParseReturn {};

template<int i>
struct Parser
{
    ParseReturn parse( const std::string& )
    {
        return ParseReturn();
    }
};

template<typename P, typename... Args>
class ParseFirst
{
public:
    static ParseReturn parse( const std::string& s )
    {
        try
        {
            return P().parse( s );
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            return ParseFirst<Args...>::parse( s );
        }
    }
};

template<typename P>
class ParseFirst<P>
{
public:
    static ParseReturn parse( const std::string& s )
    {
        try
        {
            return P().parse( s );
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            // re-throw maybe?
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string s;
    ParseFirst< Parser<1>, Parser<2> >::parse( s );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP has ruled out variadic templates since he's said that c++11 is disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a factory-like method with interface like

```
ParserPtr CreateParser(unsinged level)
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case 0: 
            return ParserPtr(new Class0);
        //...
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

and rewrite your method like

```
void Parse()
{
    unsined errorLevel = 0;
    while(auto p = CreateParser(errorLevel))
    {
        try 
        {
            p->parse(); /*...*/
            //deallocate if ParserPtr is not shared_ptr or other smart ptr
            return;
        }
        catch(Exception & e)
        {
            ++errorLevel;
            /*Extra exception handling, deallocating p if needed*/
        }
    }
    //Handle case, when no parser succeeded
}
```